# Usage of "credence"

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests, phrases, appropriate

Is it appropriate to say "gain credence from the audience"? 
 Do "give credence to a theory" and "lend credence to a theory" both work?

Comment: http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/credence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first question, if you mean to say that the audience's support was enhancing a theory's credibility (or the status of belief of something), then it should work fine.

For the second question, *"give credence to a theory"* and *"lend credence to a theory"* **should mean the same thing** (from a word-by-word standpoint, I suppose you could try to claim that "lend" is temporary, while "give" is more permanent, but as part of that phrase, there is no difference between the two, to the point where if you wanted to tell someone you'd temporarily give their theory validity, you'd have to say "temporarily lend/give credence").

http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/learner-english/credence

http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/credence
http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/lend-credence-plausibility-weight-to-something